# c# - Methods that are called from another class are not running

Tags: c#, class, methods, call

I am having trouble doing something that I would have though to have been quite simple, all I am trying to do is to call a method from another class, heres how I am calling the method:

```
Gimjes_2D_Game_Framework1.Characters.Character_One.Create();
```

and here is the contents of the method I am trying to call:

```
  public static void Create()
    {
         Form1 f = new Form1();
         System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox s = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        //location of image (in thia case it is from resources):
         s.BackgroundImage =    Gimjes_2D_Game_Framework1.Properties.Resources.DefaultSprite;
        //Set to height and width of image:
         s.Height = 64;
         s.Width = 64;
         s.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 60);
         s.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50); 
         f.Controls.Add(s);

    }
```

Comment: Define "not running". Don't compile? Runtime error? No error but doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: put a breakpoint in it

Comment: if form is not showing then u must call `f.Show()`

Comment: You need to clarify what you expect after calling this method. If you expect that your form is shown, take Baldrick`s approach. If you expect to get an instance of Form1 you need to change the return value of your method.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding

```
f.Show();
```

or

```
f.ShowDialog();
```

to the end of your `Create` method.

Otherwise, you're making a form, and never displaying it.

`Show` gives you a modeless form, and `ShowDialog` gives you a modal dialog.

See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

If you intend to *return* a `Form1` object, to be shown at a later point, you need to change your method to:

```
public static Form1 Create()
{
     Form1 f = new Form1();

     ...

     return f;
}
```

Comment: The form is already created, im using Form1 f = new Form1(); so that I can add controls to it and stuff

Comment: If you call `new Form1()`, that can only be creating a totally new `Form1` object. If you want to modify an existing `Form1` object, you need to pass that into the method, or get hold of it another way. Your current code won't be changing the existing form.

Comment: @user3349095 you are making new form every time Create() method is called.

Comment: @Baldrick how do i do that

Comment: @user3349095: Where in your code is the original form created?

Comment: Its a windows form application so i dont actually create the first form